# What purpose of setViewControllers in the case

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I saw this lines in project, that I need to understand.

```
let mainControllers = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabNavigation") as! UITabBarController
let controllers = Array(mainController.viewControllers![0..<3])
mainController.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)
self.presentViewController(mainController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What is the benefit of resetting view controllers? Thanks

Comment: Try reading the docs for Tab Bar controllers. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers:animated:

Comment: It appears to be resetting the view controllers to only be the first few of the original set of view controllers.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, why I did not see it. It is stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is limiting `mainController` to only the first 3 view controllers originally defined in the storyboard.

This code:

```
mainController.viewControllers![0..<3]
```

returns the first three elements of the original array. Then the (possibly) smaller array is used to reset the view controllers of `mainController`.